# Javascript: How to run function1 for x seconds, then function2 for y seconds, then repeat indefinitely?

Tags: javascript, timeout, intervals

I've seen several Q&A's similar to what I'm trying to figure out but haven't really helped me exactly.

What I'm wanting to do is this:

```
function1(); //for 9 seconds
stop.function1();
function2(); //for 1 second
stop.function2();
```

Then repeat this indefinitely.  I've tried a bunch of different ways with timeouts and intervals but can never get it working correctly.  I appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Update:

Function1 streams information using Key1. Function2 is identical to Function1 but uses Key2 instead. I hope that clarifies things a little.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Javascript is single-threaded, there's no way to interrupt code. Timeout functions are run from the event loop, which doesn't run until the Javascript returns.

Comment: This will be relative to what function1 and function2 do; are they expected to be indefinite functions until interrupted?. Also, is there meant to be a delay between repetitions?

Comment: Does `function1` actually run indefinitely and needs to be stopped (eg, it contains something like `while (true)`), or do you just need it to be repeatedly called for a total of 9 seconds (but each run of it only takes a short time)?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't have a feature to do something like that. (and I'm not sure if any language have). A workaround would be something like:

```
let start = new Date().getTime();
while(new Date().getTime() - start < 9000) function1();
start = new Date().getTime();
while(new Date().getTime() - start < 1000) function2();
```

It's a bad idea since the "main" thread of Javascript will be stuck doing this job for 10 seconds. But if you want the functions to be running repetidelly while the time hasn't ellapsed you have no other option. Maybe you want to put those whiles inside the functions, but that's up to you.

I belive the best approach would be to do a web worker to perform this task. The web worker would not freeze the browser, so it's a better option.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API

If you want to write less code you can ommit the getTime() call since javascript will cast the date to the number of milliseconds when the minus operation occur, but I believe the explicit way is better (but I haven't tested it).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your functions will, without modification, continue to run indefinitely, like this:

```
function1 () {
    while (true) { console.log("One more round"); }
}
```

What you probably want is to control how long these functions are run, which you can easily do by measuring the time inside the function between rounds of execution:

```
function1 () {
    var startTime = performance.now();
    while (performance.now() - startTime < 9000) { 
        console.log("One more round"); 
    }
}
```

This is a form of [co-operative multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking). Because JavaScript is inherently single-threaded, this will block execution of everything else for a whole 9 seconds. In data processing world, it's a very long time.

I suggest that you refactor your program to rely on events and timers.

To get better answers, you could improve your question by adding information on how the functions are supposed to work.